# Angular with TFS environment variables

Tags: angularjs, angular, tfs

I have this tfs variable per environment: IsInlineManualEnabled.

In my code I use it like this:

```
const IS_INLINE_MANUAL_ENABLED= process.env.IS_INLINE_MANUAL_ENABLED= '__IsInlineManualEnabled__';
```

But it doesn't work. Somebody else worked on this project and after declaring the variables in tfs, they are using them with `'__VarName__'.`

Also, I need to inject the following string "console.log('Active'); in the body of index.html.

All I did is add in index.html

```
<% if(process.env.IS_INLINE_MANUAL_ENABLED) { %>
<%= ShowSomethingInHTML %>
<$ } %>
```

Is there any other way to do this using webpack? The script I have to inject in Index.html is also a tfs variable.

The token for tfs is set correctly to accept `__VarName__`.

Comment: How did you define the tfs variable per environment? A build variable?  There is not any default tfs environment variable as `IsInlineManualEnabled`. You could have a look at this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch

Comment: It's a custom variable, not a build variable. For apps having an appconfig, it works with RM config. I have these set in webpack.prod.js and a Replace tokens which looks into .js files for `__(\w+)__`.

Comment: Hi Adrian, `Somebody else worked on this project and after declaring the variables in tfs, they are using them with '__VarName__'.` How they were using this variable in TFS, through a script or a build /release definition?  If it doesn't work, did you get any related error info. Are you using  replace tokens task  to set the `IsInlineManualEnabled` variable.